# Default value does not set when using input type is number

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 2 with Ecommerce.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" *ngFor="let deals of deals; let i = index;">
<div class=" deals-blk" *ngIf="i < 4">
    <div class="deals-blk-details clearfix">
        <div class="deals-click" (click)="dealsdetails(deals.id)">
            <h3>{{deals.D_NAME}}</h3>
            <p class="short-desc">For duration of 2hours and budget of 3K</p>
            <p class="net-val">Net Value: {{settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_SYMBOL}} {{deals.D_SALE_PRICE}}</p>
            <p class="prod-val">{{currencySymbol}} {{deals.D_REGULAR_PRICE}} + {{deals.TAX}}%
                GST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix" *ngIf="Show">
            <div class="col-sm-3 selectbox">
                <input type="number"  value="1"  [(ngModel)]="items[i]"  class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 75px;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding-left:30px;">
                <button class="col-sm-8" (click)="addtocart(deals,items,i)">ADD TO CART</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

deals is a array.I display list of product.

i declared item variable like this

```
 items=[];
```

I need default input value is '1'.

But it's not worked.

If i remove `[(ngModel)]="items[i]"` and display the value is 1

Comment: The value of your input is bound, using ngModel, to the value of `items[i]`. So if you want the value of the input to be 1, then initialize `items[i]` to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vasihuani there is two way to handle this

1. Manually initialize the value like `{{items[i] =1}}` inside your template that is not a good programming habit
2. initialize your items Array in your component class where you are fetching the data like

   `this.deals = [];// fetching from server
   this.items =[];
   for(var i=0;i<this.deals.length;i++){
     this.items[i] =1;
   }`

I would prefer second approach